# Images won't show next to each other

Tags: html, image, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

My images keep stacked underneath each other in a row, but I want them two by two next to each other, does someone see the problem?

```
<div class="contentText" id="sectieC">
    <H2>2014</H2>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
        <img src="content/img/kaart.gif"></img>
        <br></br>
        <img src="content/img/GIF_1.gif"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is what I have in my CSS:

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    max-width: 62.5rem;
}
.row:before, .row:after {
    content:" ";
    display: table;
}
.row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.row.collapse > .column, .row.collapse > .columns {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.row.collapse .row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.row .row {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: -0.9375rem;
    margin-right: -0.9375rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    max-width: none;
}
.row .row:before, .row .row:after {
    content:" ";
    display: table;
}
.row .row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.row .row.collapse {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: none;
}
.row .row.collapse:before, .row .row.collapse:after {
    content:" ";
    display: table;
}
.row .row.collapse:after {
    clear: both;
}
.column, .columns {
    padding-left: 0.9375rem;
    padding-right: 0.9375rem;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

The problem is that I didn't code this CSS, so I didn't make the thinking process and now I'm a bit lost in it. But I have to make the final result and can't contact the one who made the CSS files.

Comment: You're using Foundation, not twitter-bootstrap. I've edited the tags.

Comment: can you add your css so we can see what you are trying. A good idea would be to create jsfiddle, in the main idea this one is what you want to do, but we need more code from you https://jsfiddle.net/pnzszerw/

Answer (score 0):

See the final JSFiddle and use the code mentioned there: https://jsfiddle.net/h7fgcLnz/

Give both images a width and height like:

```
<img src="imglocation" width="200" height="200" alt="description">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added in my excisting external stylesheet, but it does nothing..

Comment: Try: .row img { float: left; } I've changed this in my post now.

Comment: I've taken a look at your CSS code. What happens if you remove all clear:both from your CSS and then use my code?

Comment: That makes that all my images go more left, which is not what I want. they also stay stacked underneath each other

Comment: I did that and it just stays the same.. al the images ranked under each other :s

Comment: @Sarah Ok, i've tried your code. Give both images a **width and height**. That will solve the problem. <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/WV-blank.svg/600px-WV-blank.svg.png" width="200" height="200" alt="Description">

Comment: In between all these solutions I tried, I gave them a width and a height, I'm sorry I didn't update this in my question. That also didn't work

Comment: Your code works in my JSFiddle when adding a width and height. So that should work for you too. Watch the code I used: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7fgcLnz/)

Comment: Yes indeed, and if I check codes fron others, it also works, but not with me. I don't understand. Maybe something is blocking it? Anyway, thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the second image around with css.
i created a fiddle:

```
<div class="contentText" id="sectieC">
<H2>2014</H2>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div id="first-image">
<img src="http://a.disquscdn.com/uploads/users/9992/2883  /avatar92.jpg?1420368091"></img>
<br></br>
<img id="second-image" src="http://a.disquscdn.com/uploads/users/9992/2883/avatar92.jpg?1420368091"></img>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#second-image{position:relative; left: 150px; bottom: 110px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hdn3bfdu/